# ASP.Net MVC with Date Picker Postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to setup an ASP.Net MVC view with a Date Picker that will send a postback to the controller when it is changed with its new date.  I know there is a Date Picker in JQuery, but how would i get it to send the data to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just attach something to the onchange on that element.

```
...
$("#datapicker").change(function(){
   $.post('someurl', data);
 }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Datepicker has an option named `onSelect`. You can pass a function to that option to post the data to server-side.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
       //post the data here
   }
});
```